# Android - Invalid Package javax.servlet.MultipartConfigElement

Tags: android

My `Android` app has a `Java` library added via a `Gradle` dependency. When trying to perform `./gradlew build`, I get the following error:

```
InvalidPackage: Package not included in Android
../../../../../../../../../.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.0.1/6bf0ebb7efd993e222fc1112377b5e92a13b38dd/javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar: Invalid package reference in library; not included in Android: javax.servlet.annotation. Referenced from javax.servlet.MultipartConfigElement.
```

I have control over the `Java` library so I can make changes. The error isn't really telling me where the reference to that is in my `library` and I can't seem to find an alternative for it.

Any ideas?

**Update**

I added the following to my `Gradle`:

```
compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.0.1'
```

But I still get the same error when doing `./gradlew build`.

Comment: did you tried  compile files('libs/javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar') in app  build.gradle

Comment: @UmarAta I'm guessing I have to download that jar and add it to my libs folder?.....Otherwise how will it recognise it?

Comment: dowload it and put it inside app/libs folder of your project then sync gradle

Comment: @UmarAta Same, still get an error. Check my Update.

Comment: well may I know for what purpose you want to use this package

Comment: @UmarAta Looking at the code, it's using `HttpServletRequest` and `Cookie`from that library.

Comment: well to store session in android you have to use shared preferences

Comment: That's got nothing to do with the `ServletHttpRequest` or `Cookie`.

Comment: to perform network request you may use httpurlconnection or apis like volley retrofit or butterknife and use shared preference to store cookies in that . If I am wrong then please elaborate what exactly you want to do with httpservletrequest and cookie

Comment: does your problem is solved

Comment: Hi @UmarAta. Luckily, the Android app isn't directly querying the incompatible methods in the Java library. So to solve the issue, i've added a 

`lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }`.

It now builds and deploys perfectly fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: ok so now can I post it as answer to help others

Answer (score 0):

As per our discussion in comment . This error can be ignored by using the following code in gradle

`lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }`

Comment: This isn't a solution to the question. Furthermore, it isn't your solution - it's mine :|